# draw array images in canvas?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, canvas

I am trying to draw an array of images on a canvas, but nothing is getting drawn! following is my code! Also i am trying to learn about phonegap and javascript
index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Minecraft Background Check</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="mycanvas" style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; border:1px solid #c3c3c3; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("deviceready",ondeviceReady,false);
function onDeviceReady () {}
    //get element by id 
var c = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    //array image which need to draw in canvas
var image = ["img/image12","img/image13","img/image14","img/image15","img/image10"];
var m_arrImages = {};
for (var src in image) {
    m_arrImages[src] = new Image();

    m_arrImages[src].src = image[src];
}
var imagePositionsX = [20, 80, 140, 200, 260, 320, 380, 440, 500, 560];
var imagePositionsY = [20, 60, 100, 140, 180, 220, 260, 300, 340, 380];
var i, x, y;
for (i = 0; i < m_arrImages.length; i++) {
    x = imagePositionsX[ Math.floor(Math.random()*10) ];
    y = imagePositionsY[ Math.floor(Math.random()*10) ];

    ctx.drawImage(m_arrImages[i], x, y, 50, 50);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have set the function `ondeviceReady` to run at the `deviceready` event but that function isn't defined. You have defined a function called `onDeviceReady`. Javascript variable and function names are case sensitive, so nothing will run at the `deviceready` event.

Change:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",ondeviceReady,false);
```

to

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
```

Answer (score 1):

May be I am wrong, but.. "m_arrImages" - it's just array with strings, not images, isn't it?

I thing, it sould be something like that:

```
var m_arrImages = {};
for (var src in image) {
    m_arrImages[src] = new Image();
    m_arrImages[src].src = image[src];
}
```